# How to expand a NTFS partition that is in the middle?

Tags: windows, vmware-esxi, hard-drive, partition, disk-volume

I am running into an issue expanding my C:\ drive, which is in the middle and I have carved space before/after it for other stuff.

This is a virtual environment (VMware) and the OS is Windows 2012 R2.

I expanded the VMDK disk by +40GB so that I can expand my C:\ partition, I have done this in the past many times but never in a scenario where the partition is not last on the disk.

So if I select to expand C:\ it is grayed out, but I an expand X:.

What's the supported way of expanding C:\? This also happens to be our Exchange server so I am worried running linux based tools such as Gparted on Windows volumes/partitions..

Thanks.[image: disk management]

Comment: The simple answer is that you shouldn't have created the X: partition, and if you delete it you can expand C:  I can't think of any sensible reasons for creating a 1GB partition directly after your C:\ partition, why did you do that?

Comment: I did this because the X:\ partition holds mount points for other volumes as folders and I did not want to add the mount points of other volumes to the C:\ drive. Deleting X:\ is not an option at all.

Comment: Gparted is perfectly capable of handling this.

Answer (score 4):

Gparted works well, even for windows so don't worry about it ! by the way i didn't found something as powerfull as Gparted for windows.
Use Gparted live to boot on the iso, the graphic interface will help you to extand your partition.

Answer (score 1):

With a Basic volume/partition on a Basic disk the free space has to be adjacent to the volume/partition you want to extend. You'll need to either delete X: in order to extend C:, or you'll need to use a tool like GParted>